# AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames returns cannotComplete in Cocoa App but works well in playground

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm trying to build an utility in navigating to any visible & enabled ui-element without mouse or trackpad, so I have to enumerate those elements first.

I did some research and found maybe Accessibility APIs would help me to reach my goal. Then I tried them in **playground** as below :

```
//...
let key: String = kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as String
let options = [key: true]
let enabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options as CFDictionary)

if !enabled {
    print("Not permitted")
    NSApp.terminate(nil)
}

//...

let element = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid as! pid_t)
var ans : CFArray?
let e = AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(element, &ans)
if e == .success, let names = ans as? [String] {
    print(names)
}
//...
```

It works well in playground. Then I created a new Cocoa App, copied codes above into it, ran it in debug mode, and AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames return an AXError - cannotComplete.

It's very sure Xcode is enabled in System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility. AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions always returns true seems that it's not an issue of permission.

How can I make it works? Did I miss any necessary setting?

I'm not good in English, sorry about that.

Comment: please can you format the question properly.

Comment: If you want your app to be able to use the Accessibility API, then you also have to enable your app (not Xcode) in System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility. (Enabling Xcode is necessary for the playground to have access, but doesn't affect your app.)

Comment: @KenThomases AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions always returns true seems that it's not an issue of permission, the application was launched by Xcode in debug mode, maybe enable Xcode in Accessibility is enough. However I've tried your suggestion, and the issue is still there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PragatiSingh I'm new here, would you please tell me where I can find something about what a correct question format looks like.

Comment: please can you check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by turning off App Sandbox. I'm still curious why there is not accessibility entitlement in sandbox. Given that I have no plan to put my app in Mac App Store, to turn off App Sandbox is a solution for me.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

"With App Sandbox, you can and should enable your app for accessibility, as described in Accessibility Programming Guide for OS X. However, you cannot sandbox an assistive app such as a screen reader, and you cannot sandbox an app that controls another app."

Excerpt from  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html

Playgrounds are not sandboxed and that is why it worked there.